# Efecto blur sin que afecte al texto CSS

Tags: html, css

Tengo un problema que al querer hacer un un efecto blur al fondo de mi div, lo hace pero también afecta al texto y a la imagen, cosa que no quiero que haga y ya probé subiendo el z-index de los elementos que no quiero que tengan el efecto pero no hace nada, dejo mi código:

```
<div class="seccion">
  <div class="edu-title">
    <h4 class="title">EDUCACION</h4>
    <ul class="edu-iconos" *ngIf="isLogged">
      <li (click)="mostrarFormEdu()">
        <a>
          <fa-icon [icon]="faPlus" class="icono1"></fa-icon>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="educacion" *ngFor="let edu of educacion">
    <div class="todo d-flex">
      <img src="../../../assets/img/educacion.png" class="d-none d-md-block imagen-trabajo">
      <div class="parte d-flex ">
        <p class="nombre fw-bold text-capitalize">{{edu.nombreEdu}}</p>
        <p class=" text-capitalize titulo">{{edu.tituloEdu}}</p>
      </div>
      <ul *ngIf="isLogged" class="edu-iconos">
        <li (click)="editEdu(edu.id)">
          <a>
            <fa-icon [icon]="faPenToSquare" class="icono1"></fa-icon>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li (click)="deleteEdu(edu.id)">
          <a>
            <fa-icon [icon]="faTrashCan" class="icono1"></fa-icon>
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <p class="fechas">{{edu.fechaInicioEdu}} - {{edu.fechaFinEdu}}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
.seccion{
     box-shadow: 0 0 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, .9);
     margin-top: 0.625rem;
     padding: 0.9375rem;
     border-radius: 1.25rem;
     box-sizing: border-box;
     width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Buenas noches, quizás te podría ser útil leer [ask], en general lo ideal es que subas el mínimo código verificable, es decir lo necesario para poder realizar las pruebas pertinentes y poder ayudarte en el menor tiempo posible, también en este caso exactamente a quien le quieres dar el blur y que código estás utilizando para hacerlo, de esa forma es más sencillo reproducir tu problema y ayudarte a solucionarlo.